# Azure workerservice as webjob timer nullreference

Tags: c#, azure, cron

We have a worker service running on azure as a webjob deployed as part of our build pipeline.

The webapp and webjob are both running. But it seems after my worker schedules a task internally, the timer elapses as expected but the timer dispose throws an exception.

This is a .net 6 worker and this is the only way I could add the cron stuff.

This worker schedules multiple stuff. I just added the first one in for reference.

I know the process kicks off because it shows a console log I did namely `--Getting parts from staging`

So it starts the process but immediately breaks on the dispose killing the whole program so the timed service does not do what its supposed to.

Any help will be appreciated.

Worker:

```
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting Scheduler");
            await ScheduleTasks(stoppingToken);
        }

        private async Task ScheduleTasks(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _tasks = new List<Task>();

            //Service Setup
            IWorker partsWorker = new PartsWorker(_configuration, _mapper, _mpwContext, _partContext);

            //Schedule service

            _tasks.Add(ScheduleJob(stoppingToken, "0 10 * * *", partsWorker));

            await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
        }

        protected async Task ScheduleJob(CancellationToken stoppingToken, string cronExpression, IWorker task)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Task Scheduled");
            var expression = CronExpression.Parse(cronExpression);
            var next = expression.GetNextOccurrence(DateTimeOffset.Now, _timeZoneInfo);
            if (next.HasValue)
            {
                var delay = next.Value - DateTimeOffset.Now;
                if (delay.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
                {
                    await ScheduleJob(stoppingToken, cronExpression, task);
                }
                _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(delay.TotalMilliseconds);
                _timer.Elapsed += async (sender, args) =>
                {
                    _timer.Dispose();    <-------NullReference
                    _timer = null;

                    if (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Starting Job...");
                        await task.ExecuteAsync(stoppingToken);
                        _logger.LogInformation("Timer fired");
                    }

                    if (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        await ScheduleJob(stoppingToken, cronExpression, task);
                    }
                };
                _timer.Start();
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Output of webjob logs:

```
[03/05/2022 21:17:38 > 779765: INFO]       Task Scheduled
[03/05/2022 21:17:38 > 779765: INFO] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[03/05/2022 21:17:38 > 779765: INFO]       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[03/05/2022 21:17:38 > 779765: INFO] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[03/05/2022 21:17:38 > 779765: INFO]       Hosting environment: Production
[03/05/2022 21:17:38 > 779765: INFO] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[03/05/2022 21:17:38 > 779765: INFO]       Content root path: C:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\BatchOrderCreationService\qhgroswi.st3
[03/05/2022 21:31:08 > cedd25: INFO] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[03/05/2022 21:31:08 > cedd25: INFO]       Application is shutting down...
[03/05/2022 21:31:12 > cedd25: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
[03/05/2022 21:31:12 > cedd25: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds
[03/05/2022 21:31:12 > cedd25: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[03/05/2022 21:31:12 > cedd25: SYS INFO] Run script 'Mpw.OrderEngineWorkerService.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[03/05/2022 21:31:12 > cedd25: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/05/2022 21:31:17 > cedd25: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1073740791
[03/05/2022 21:31:17 > cedd25: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[03/05/2022 21:31:17 > cedd25: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[03/05/2022 22:17:24 > 779765: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[03/06/2022 08:00:00 > 779765: INFO] info: Mpw.OrderEngineWorkerService.Worker[0]
[03/06/2022 08:00:00 > 779765: INFO]       Starting Job...
[03/06/2022 08:00:00 > 779765: INFO] --Getting parts from staging
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ] Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ]    at Mpw.OrderEngineWorkerService.Worker.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<ScheduleJob>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Mpw\BatchOrderCreationService\Worker.cs:line 79
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ]    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ]    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: SYS INFO] Run script 'Mpw.OrderEngineWorkerService.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[03/06/2022 08:00:01 > 779765: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/06/2022 08:00:04 > 779765: INFO] info: Mpw.OrderEngineWorkerService.Worker[0]
[03/06/2022 08:00:04 > 779765: INFO]       Starting Scheduler
[03/06/2022 08:00:04 > 779765: INFO] info: Mpw.OrderEngineWorkerService.Worker[0]
[03/06/2022 08:00:04 > 779765: INFO]       Task Scheduled
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a `System.Threading.Timer` that can be changed, and is only disposed on application shutdown.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0